# ActionScript 3.0 remove sprite from array element

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, object, sprite

I have a question for as3.How can i remove sprite from array

```
    var object:Object;
    var objectArray:Array;
    var objectSprite:Sprite;

    for(...) {
        objectArray.push(object);
    }
    for(...) {
        objectSprite.graphics.drawCircle(objectArray.x, objectArray.y,objectArray.radius);
        addChild(objectSprite);
    }
    if(3 > 2) {
        objectArray.splice(object, 1);
        // how can i remove screen the object sprite and object from array
    }
```

Comment: Because the AS3 manual doesn't tell you??? Try google for add/removing items in an array and also search for how to **remove** Child on stage (the opposite of **add**ing as Child)...

Comment: i search but i cant find anything.i can remove array.but i cant remove on screen the sprite object.

Comment: `removeChild(objectSprite)`

Comment: @MartonPallagi, I was afraid of that. Asker should know the basics!! Programmers are problem solvers and this one couldn't even find these **[google search results](https://www.google.com/#q=as3+remove+object+from+stage)**

Comment: i try but removeChild(objectSprite) remove every sprite object. ex:if(objectArray[objectSprite].radius >30) objectArray.splice(..); and remove objectSprite radius > 30; how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

- Check the manual for **[Array.splice](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice())** usage. `objectArray.splice( xyz, 1);` where `xyz` is the number of entries to **start from**. Why you put `object` instead of a number?
- In your second for-loop you could try `objectSprite = new Sprite;` before making the drawCircle code etc so each one **is new** and has **unique name**. Maybe that will fix your "they all get deleted" issue. To remove, you can just do: `removeChild( container.getChildByName(someName4) );`

An example of how your For-Loop could be made...

```
var container : Sprite = new Sprite; //one container for ALL objects
addChild( container); // add to stage

for ( j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{

    objectSprite = new Sprite; //make a new unique one
    objectSprite.name = "myName" + String( j );
    objectSprite.graphics.drawCircle(objectArray.x, objectArray.y,objectArray.radius);
    container.addChild(objectSprite); //add into container

    trace ("new objectSprite - Name is : " +  objectSprite.name);
}
```

As for removing try something like below..

```
if(3 > 2) 
{
    //# Check name to be sure you are removing right one...
    //# yourNum is order you added (1st= 0, 2nd= 1, 3rd= 2, etc)
    trace ( "Object to remove is : " + objectArray[ yourNum ].name );

    //# How can i remove from screen (stage??) the object sprite
    //# yourName example is : "someName4"
    container.removeChild( container.getChildByName("yourName") ); 

    //# And remove object from array?
    objectArray.splice( yourNum, 1);

}
```

PS: The code is untested in Flash but gives you an idea of how to make this. If you get errors with it, Stop - Think - Fix them.

I'm puzzled by this line: 
 `objectSprite.graphics.drawCircle(objectArray.x, objectArray.y,objectArray.radius);`. 
An array is just an idea of "group of items" so really how does this list have an **x**, **y** and even **radius**?? Wait, don't tell me. Somehow it's working alright for you so I'll stop there..

Comment: Thank you very much.Then i can remove sprite and object on the screen.

Comment: Are you telling me it worked ok, or asking me if this will work?

Comment: İts working thank you and sorry i cant speak english because i am turkish :)

Comment: Please tick the green mark (✓) to show there is now a solution for this. Glad it's ok for you. No worries about language.